# openssl_encrypt(): iv key passed is 24 bytes long which is longer than the 16 expected

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, openssl

I am using openssl_encrypt in Laravel, i used this function before in PHP 5.6 which was working ok, but after i switched to Laravel, i took the encryption and decryption functions from my old web application but i am getting the following error:

> ```
> openssl_encrypt(): IV passed is 24 bytes long which is longer than the 16 expected by selected cipher, truncating
> ```

```
private $iv = "########################";
private $keys = "###########";

protected function encryption($plainData)
    {


        $cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
        $encryptedData = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainData, $cipher, $this->keys, 1,$this->iv));
        return $encryptedData;

    }
    //decryption
    protected function decryption($encryptedData)
    {

        $decodeData = base64_decode($encryptedData);
        $cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
        $data = openssl_decrypt($decodeData, $cipher, $this->keys, 1,$this->iv);
        return $data;

    }
```

Anyone has any insight, in which way i can fix this issue?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  Are you sure you have the correct iv there?

Comment: Yeah, i am using the same old iv, it's 24 characters long.

Comment: Its not an error, its a warning. The openssl_encrypt() function is not a laravel provided interface - if you have changed something its got nothing to do with Laravel. The IV you have shown us here is 24 ASCII characters long - just like the message tells you (BTW using a static IV rather defeats the prupose. Nothing about what you are asking makes any sense to me.

Comment: I would humbly suggest it should be 16 characters long...

Comment: Well, It's an error. Atleast that's what i got in Laravel: ErrorException. So, i have records in the database that have been encrypted with that same key and iv. If i change the iv in the Laravel and make it random it doesn't work. I don't have good experience in cryptography so this notions are not familiar.

Comment: It's likely the IV was always getting truncated, it was just quiet about it on your previous installation. See this regarding a static IV https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22260/cbc-with-a-fixed-or-random-iv

Comment: But, how does truncation happens. Does it remove the remaining characters from the end?

Comment: I was just checking my database, the encrypted password from the old web app is 32 characters long, after i truncated the iv i got a 24 long encrypted character. Makes me believe the iv doesn't get truncated in the old web app.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to talk about a 24 bytes init Vector (**IV**) for **AES**. 
The **IV** is only applied to the first encryption block, and as **AES** works with encryption block of 16 bytes, the IV needs to be 16 bytes. Specifying more than 16 bytes for the **IV** will inherently involve some truncation if not outright giving you an error (you seem to have encountered both cases).

As for the use of the **IV**, you should not use a hard coded value, but rather use a unique **IV** for each message. As the **IV** is unique for a message you need to store it together with the message. It is a common practice to preprend the message with the **IV**, so it's handy when you need to decrypt the message.